# How to get the logged in user details(user email id and user name) using Access Token in AAD Single Sign on using java script back-end?

Tags: authentication, windows-store-apps, azure-active-directory

Hi am developing a windows store 8.1 app using C# and xaml

For log in, am authenticating the user with Windows Azure Active directory Single Sign-on using JavaScript back-end.

Once the user is logged in and i have the access token, how to get the logged in  user's user email id and Username using the access token in the app?

Anybody please provide me a solution to get the user email using the access token?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the access token then that should contain the user id value. For retrieving the e-mail address you have to query the Graph API to get user details. The full documentation on that is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151678.aspx) but in short you should make a get request like below, placing the AccessToken in the Authorization header, after "Bearer ".

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/Alex@contoso.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=2013-04-05 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX ... FWSXfwtQ
Content-Type: application/json
```

You can use either user principal name or objectId in the address. Better yet, you can use the [Azure AD Graph Client nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) and call their API to get user information.

```
Uri servicePointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, "contoso.onmicrosoft.com");
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, accessToken);
IUser user = activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .Where(user => user.UserPrincipalName.Equals("alex@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"))
    .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList().SingleOrDefault();
```

[See here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs#L217) for the full sample.