# Get system userinfo in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to implement SSO capabilitites in a spring boot application. 
I need to fetch the current logged in OS-user (windows) in order to lookup in the Active Directory and retrieve the roles.

I have seen some samples with the use of **SecurityContextHolder**, but this seems to be relevant for web application with integrated authentication mechanisms.

Any idea how to fetch the current windows user in a spring application?

Thanks

Comment: You don't generally need a password to look up roles/group-membership in an AD. A service account could do that (would require its credentials, but not the current user's), or if appropriate, it may already be world-readable.

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590227/how-to-retrieve-the-current-windows-logged-on-user-for-single-sign-on-purposes-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226277/how-to-get-the-logged-in-user-detailsuser-email-id-and-user-name-using-access

Answer (score 0):

Try this,may works on ie and chrome:

```
    public String  WindowsUserDemo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (auth == null) {
                response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
                try {
                    response.flushBuffer();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (auth.startsWith("NTLM ")) {
                byte[] msg = new byte[0];
                try {
                    msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int off = 0, length, offset;
                if (msg[8] == 1) {
                    byte z = 0;
                    byte[] msg1 = { (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L', (byte) 'M', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P',
                            z, (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, (byte) 40, z, z, z, (byte) 1, (byte) 130, z, z, z,
                            (byte) 2, (byte) 2, (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z };
                    response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1));
                    try {
                        response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (msg[8] == 3) {
                    off = 30;

                    length = msg[off + 17] * 256 + msg[off + 16];
                    offset = msg[off + 19] * 256 + msg[off + 18];
                    String remoteHost = new String(msg, offset, length);

                    length = msg[off + 1] * 256 + msg[off];
                    offset = msg[off + 3] * 256 + msg[off + 2];
                    String domain = new String(msg, offset, length);

                    length = msg[off + 9] * 256 + msg[off + 8];
                    offset = msg[off + 11] * 256 + msg[off + 10];
                    String username = new String(msg, offset, length);

                    return remoteHost+"name:"+username+",domain:"+domain;
                }
            }
            return "error";
}
```